# Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have error when client  need to buy from may website 
in admin page always make the orders in failed status
and the state of my payment plugin is like the image
But the buy process from ipay88 plugin is good without any error and the money
transfer between account

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwD1p.jpg)

Comment: Contact the developer of the ipay88 plugin. This is not a general support forum!

Answer (score 2):

If you tested with the current version of WooCommerce just add bellow text inside

```
WC requires at least: 2.6
WC tested up to: 3.7
```

here is a full example

```
Plugin Name: Smart Variation Swatches for WooCommerce
Plugin URI: https://athemeart.com/downloads/variation-swatches-style-for-woocommerce/
Description: An extension of WooCommerce that make variable products be more beauty and friendly with customers.
Version: 1.3
Author: aThemeArt
Author URI: http://athemeart.com/
License: GPLv2 or later
Requires at least: 4.4
Tested up to: 5.2
WC requires at least: 2.6
WC tested up to: 3.7
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
```